# How to use pyqt widget event() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Exactly how do I utilize the various event methods that widgets have? Say I have a comboBox(drop down list) and I want to initiate a function every time someone changes the choice. There is the changeEvent() method in the documentation but It would be great if someone explains to me with a piece of code.

Comment: Don't use events, use [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#signals).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question.  I recommend checking out the many tutorials on Youtube.com.

However, in your **init** method, put something like this:

`self.ui.charge_codes_combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setup_payments)`

In my example, the combo box was placed on a form in Qt Designer.  Self.setup_payment is a method triggered by the change in the combo box.

I hope this helps!